# Swift Delegates not working for updating timer to receiver

Tags: swift, timer, delegates

I have created protocol as updateTime protocol to update timer to other view controllers conform to updateTime delegates but the timer not updating to other controllers.

Please refer below code and pin point where I did wrong?

```
protocol UpdateTime: class {
    func updateTIme(count: Int)
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UpdateTime {

    @IBOutlet var timeLabel: UILabel!

    let secVC = SecondViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        secVC.delegate = self
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    // must be internal or public.
     func updateTIme(count: Int){

        print("firstVC: \(count)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.timeLabel.text = "\(count)"
        }

    }



}


class Counter {
    var count = 0
    func increment() {
        count += 1
    }
    func increment(by amount: Int) -> Int{
        count += amount

        print(count)
        return count
    }
    func reset() {
        count = 0
    }
}
```

This is seconviewcontroller:

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!
        weak var delegate: UpdateTime?
        var counter = Counter()
        var timer = Timer()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.timer.invalidate()



    self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target:   self, selector: #selector(self.countDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

            }

        }

        @objc func countDown() -> Int{
            // counter increments
            counter.increment()
            let count = counter.increment(by: 5)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.label.text = String(describing: count)


            }
            self.delegate?.updateTIme(count: count)


            return count

        }

    }
```

The label in view controller not updating count down.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a lifecycle issue. Though you are creating an instance of `SecondViewController`, the timer from the second view controller only gets added to the run loop when that view controller's `viewDidLoad` method is called. Since  you are programmatically creating it in the first view controller, there is nowhere in your example that would cause the second view controller's view to get loaded, so the timer would not be added to the runloop.

A better way of accomplishing this issue is to create the timer on the first view controller directly, or create a secondary object (not a second view controller) that manages the timer and have it push updates to the first view controller